# Scraping Data issue getting a list item python

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm using beautifulsoup for Python2.7 and in the middle of reading an html file in the following way:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")  
year= soup.find("i",{"class":"fa fa-calendar-o"})
```

I'm looking to get the year 2011 from the following html and I'm not getting the value all I get is `<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>`. Can someone help me and explain what I've done wrong? Thanks.

```
</div>
        <!-- /.section-title -->
        <div class="available clearfix">
            <h5 class="pull-left"><!--Available from--> </h5>
            <div class="pull-right"> <div class="feedback-rating" data-score="4"></div> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-body">
            <ul class="list-info">
                <li> <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Manual </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-tint"></i> Petrol </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 2011 </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Airport (YYZ) </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.list-info -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 2011 is in the `<li> </li>` no  in the `<i></i>` tag, so try this:

```
  i = soup.find("i",{"class":"fa fa-calendar-o"}) 
  year = i.parent.getText()
```

**EDIT**

explanation:

with `.parent` you can access to the parent element, in this case `.parent` give you 
`<li> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 2011 </li>`, if you do `.parent` again that returns

```
<ul class="list-info">
                <li> <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Manual </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-tint"></i> Petrol </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 2011 </li>
                <li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Airport (YYZ) </li>
            </ul>
```

for more see the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent)

Comment: This works perfectly, so what exactly is being done with parent.getText()?